# Odd Date("Y-m-d") result

Tags: php, date

Im having some bizarre results in regards to the php date() function. Basically Im getting a date from a Mysql database which is in a string format, split into three elements. This would be Day, Month, Year (15 september 2012 for example) Im ultimately comparing two dates to see if it has expired. But the issue is that only certain dates are allowing the code to work, and some do not work at all (or allow the if statement to work effectively) Below is my code, any help would be great.

```
 $today = date("d-m-Y");

$expire = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($this->getData('date_day')."-".
$this->getData('date_month')."-".$this->getData('date_year'))) ;

 if ($expire < $today)
{
    echo 'expired';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not expired';
}
```

Im sure its something simple, but for some reason I cannot solve it.

Comment: Could you add some examples of dates that don't work?

Comment: Could we trouble you to provide the specific use-cases you mentioned?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that anything from the 13th of the month and later doesn't work?

Comment: An example is that 15-09-2010 is rendering within the if statment as Not expired. When clearly that day has passed.

Comment: Could you try that again, formatted as '09-15-2010'?

Comment: @andrewsi You are right, anyway I can resolve this issue?

Comment: @LeeMarshall - I've added an answer; but I'd suggest you implement Stephen305's :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare the Unix timestamps.

```
$today = time();

$expire = strtotime($this->getData('date_day')."-".
$this->getData('date_month')."-".$this->getData('date_year')) ;

if ($expire > $today)
{
    echo 'expired';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not expired';
}
```

Comment: Very good call Stephen305 I never thought about using time(). Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `strtotime` is expected a US date format; you need to swap the month and the day around to generate a valid date:

```
$today = date("d-m-Y");

$expire = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($this->getData('date_month')."-".
$this->getData('date_day')."-".$this->getData('date_year'))) ;
```

On the other hand, see Stephen305's answer - it's a much better solution to your problem.